I'm trying to identify a TV show as well as a specific episode dealing with psychic abilities
I saw this within the last three-four years, probably on Netflix or Amazon. 
The show may have been British, the episode I saw took place there, London I think. 
It was a show about psychic abilities and involved this one demonstration of a psychic(male) standing in front of a screen so that he was not visible to his audience of a small classical orchestra. 
He then attempted to telepathically cause the musicians to play a piece that he had in mind and was psychically "sending" to them. The orchestra was instructed to tune up and then play what ever they thought they were picking up. As they tuned up they all began to synchronize and morph into Beethoven's "Ode to Joy". 
The psychic then revealed his target piece that he had written on a board and it was of course Ode to Joy

If it's British, then the most likely candidate would be Dynamo: Magician Impossible.

Although the details are a little different, I believe this was an episode of Derren Brown: Trick of the Mind,



The conductor is given a song by Derren and has his hands tied behind his back. The idea is that the orchestra could pick up the conductor's cues without the use of his hands, i.e. from facial expressions only. The song in question was revealed to be "Ode to Joy".
Hosted by the UK mentalist Derren Brown. I couldn't find the exact broadcast date, season or episode number though.

I would have guessed Derren Brown. This guys is amazing.
